# How do I move my bullet list to the center while having them vertically aligned in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm not sure what I did wrong but the bullet points on the unordered lists are shifted to the far left of the page while the contents remain in the center. What's the best way to move the bullet points back to the center while having them vertically aligned so they don't look unorganized?

Here's a link to my codepen project:

https://codepen.io/danielanggggg/pen/LYjwOer

HTML

```css
#welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 10vw;
  left: 2vw;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1>Daniel Ang</h1>
  <h3>Freelance Copywriter</h3>
  <p>Hi there! I'm Daniel. I specialize in direct-response copywriting. I believe you are looking<br> for a copywriter to increase your conversion rate and ultimately sell your products or services.</p>
  <p>I specialize in writing:</p>
  <ul>
<li>Emails</li>
<li>Landing Pages</li>
<li>Sales Letters</li>
<li>Product Descriptions</li>
<li>Facebook/Instagram Ads</li>
  </ul>
  <p>If you need any of the services above, please don't hesitate to reach out!</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I add below code and fixed!

```
ul{
   width: max-content;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can change width as much as you want for example `width: 20%;` or use `width: max-content;` for dynamic width.

```css
#welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 10vw;
  left: 2vw;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}

ul {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1>Daniel Ang</h1>
  <h3>Freelance Copywriter</h3>
  <p>Hi there! I'm Daniel. I specialize in direct-response copywriting. I believe you are looking<br> for a copywriter to increase your conversion rate and ultimately sell your products or services.</p>
  <p>I specialize in writing:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Emails</li>
    <li>Landing Pages</li>
    <li>Sales Letters</li>
    <li>Product Descriptions</li>
    <li>Facebook/Instagram Ads</li>
  </ul>
  <p>If you need any of the services above, please don't hesitate to reach out!</p>
</section>
```

Comment: We can achieve this without changing width. Changing width can also cause text wrapping for large text.

Comment: @Ishtiaq by using `width: max-content;` the problem will be fixed!

Comment: `width: max-content;` is fine. But I am talking about `width: 20%;` which is added for `ul`.

Comment: @Ishtiaq it's depend on project and purpose, in this situation `width: 20%;` works fine, but for dynamic width using `width: max-content;` worked!

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is to try to use [Flex - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) in order to achieve this. If you have not installed it yet, feel free to do it, because it is going to help you a lot. I would include the list inside div classes, as shown below:

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-sm-row" >

   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center d-flex align-items-end flex-fill">
      <ul>
        <li>
        ...
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: why should he be installing stuff? It can be done in css

Comment: @Dev You are right. I have already upvoted the answer of kian.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flex box with column direction to get what you want without specifying a width for your bullet list.

```css
#welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  /* height is changed to min-height so the actual height will still be calculated based on content when 100vh is smaller than the height of your content */
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 10vw;
  left: 2vw;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/fredns/pen/QWqNLOb

Answer (score 0):

wrap `ul` in div and use css as below:

```css
#welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 10vw;
  left: 2vw;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.wrap{
display:flex
}
ul{
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1>Daniel Ang</h1>
  <h3>Freelance Copywriter</h3>
  <p>Hi there! I'm Daniel. I specialize in direct-response copywriting. I believe you are looking<br> for a copywriter to increase your conversion rate and ultimately sell your products or services.</p>
  <p>I specialize in writing:</p>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
<li>Emails</li>
<li>Landing Pages</li>
<li>Sales Letters</li>
<li>Product Descriptions</li>
<li>Facebook/Instagram Ads</li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <p>If you need any of the services above, please don't hesitate to reach out!</p>
</section>
```

Comment: you can use `ul,li{text-align:initial;}` to stick li to the dots, which means center only the ul

Answer (score 0):

You can add following `CSS` for `ul` and `li` and this will solve your issue.

```
ul li {
    text-align: left;
}

ul {
    width: fit-content;        
    margin: auto;
}
```

So your complete code will be;

```css
 #welcome-section {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            top: 10vw;
            left: 2vw;
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10rem;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #navbar {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            background-color: grey;
        }

        ul li {
            text-align: left;
        }

        ul {
            width: fit-content;
            margin: auto;
        }
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section">
        <h1>Daniel Ang</h1>
        <h3>Freelance Copywriter</h3>
        <p>Hi there! I'm Daniel. I specialize in direct-response copywriting. I believe you are looking<br> for a copywriter to increase your conversion rate and ultimately sell your products or services.</p>
        <p>I specialize in writing:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Emails</li>
            <li>Landing Pages</li>
            <li>Sales Letters</li>
            <li>Product Descriptions</li>
            <li>Facebook/Instagram Ads</li>
        </ul>
        <p>If you need any of the services above, please don't hesitate to reach out!</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: Works fine and according to requirement